# How can i place a regex pattern inside another regex pattern without having mismatches

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my regex pattern (without spaces atm):

```
(method)\((.*?),(.*?)\)|(print)\((.*?)\)
```

And the result always returns:

```
"method(a,print(hello world)"
```

instead of:

```
"method(a,print(hello world))"
```

How can I capture everything while still keeping the outer brackets?

Comment: What language? JavaScript, Python, ...?

Comment: c# sorry I didn't add it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but wouldn't you just add another `\)` to the end? Or effectively, add a `{2}` to capture 2 parentheses?

Comment: I want to be able to add multiple things inside method(a, #) where # is a string with () or without it. For eg. "method(a, print(hello) wait(5) cls; print(hello world))", no matter what I put in place of # I want it to maintain the outer brackets including the string inside it.

Comment: Try this: ((?:method|print)\(([^,]+)(?:,([^,]+))?\))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a special construct called balancing groups to achieve recursiveness and capture more than one level of nesting in a method, should it be required. The commands captured are placed inside of the group "commands"

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"method
[(]
(?<action>\w+)\s*,\s*
(\s*
    (?<commands>\w+
    (;|
        ((?<open>[(])[^(]*?)+
        (?<close-open>[)])+
        (?(open)(?!))
    ))+
\s*)+
[)]", RegexOptions.IgnoreWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Here is a [permalink](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=method%0d%0a%5b%28%5d%0d%0a%28%3f%3caction%3e%5cw%2b%29%5cs*%2c%5cs*%0d%0a%28%5cs*%0d%0a++++%28%3f%3ccommands%3e%5cw%2b%0d%0a++++%28%3b%7c%0d%0a++++++++%28%28%3f%3copen%3e%5b%28%5d%29%5b%5e%28%5d*%3f%29%2b%0d%0a++++++++%28%5b%5e%28%5d*%28%3f%3cclose-open%3e%5b%29%5d%29%29%2b%0d%0a++++++++%28%3f%28open%29%28%3f!%29%29%0d%0a++++%29%29%2b%0d%0a%5cs*%29%2b%0d%0a%5b%29%5d&i=method%28a%2cprint%28hello+world%29%29%0d%0amethod%28a%2c+print%28foo%28bar%28baz%28bass%28blast%29%29%29%29%29+wait%285%29+cls%3b+print%28hello+world%29%29&o=xn) to the regex. If you look in there, you will see the follwing table as a result:

[image]

As seen here, the regex has matched 4 commands in the 2nd line, under in which the action is `a`, in order to get those results, you can do `regex.Match(foo).Groups["commands"].Captures.Select(c => c.Value)`